# Number of pairs of multisets of integers satisfying arithmetic patterns

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

Let $n,\ell \geq 2$ be integers. For an integer $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$ and two multisets $A, B$ each consisting of $\ell$ numbers in $[n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, we say that $A, B$ satisfy the pattern $R_k$, and write $A R_k B$, if the following two conditions hold:

(1) The elements of $A$ are the same as those of $B$, except for exactly two.

(2) Let $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ be the two elements in $A,B$, respectively, which differ. Then $(b_1, b_2) = (a_1 - k, a_2 + k+1)$ or $(b_2, b_1) = (a_1 - k, a_2 + k+1)$.

For example, let $A = \{\{ 4,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3\}\}$ and $B = \{\{3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,3\}\}$. Then $AR_1 B$ with $a_1 = 4$, $a_2 = 1$, $b_1 = b_2 = 3$.

Now for a given number $m$, let $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ be given multisets, each of size $\ell$ consisting of numbers in $[n]$. I am interested in obtaining an upper bound for 
$$
S = \#\{(k, i,j) \in [n] \times [m]^2 \ : \ A_i R_k A_j \}
$$
in terms of $m,n,\ell$.

Perhaps a probabilistic method works here? Maybe starting with this: Choose $m$ multisets $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ from $[n]$ uniformly at random, each of size $\ell$. Let
$$
X_{i,j,k} = \begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if } A_i R_k A_j\\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Now let 
$$X = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq m} X_{i,j,k}.$$
Now $U = U(m,n,\ell)$ is an upper bound for $S$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(X \leq U) = 1$. Perhaps the Chebyshev's inequality could work here? Note we need to find a $U$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq U) \geq 1$.

Comment: I don't understand condition (2) at all. Why are there *four* values for the *two* elements that differ? (If $x$ is an element of $A$ that appears with a  different multiplicity in $B$, shouldn't $x$ also be an element of $B$ that appears with a  different multiplicity in $A$?) Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes I see that my original definition was a bit ambiguous. I added an example now and updated the definition. I'm more interested in the method here than in the actual relation R. One could replace it with other similar arithmetic relation.

Comment: I gave another example; the previous one was slightly off.

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, is it true that a trivial upper bound is $\binom{m}{2}$ (because for any $A_i$ and $A_j$, there is at most one $k$ such that $A_i R_k A_j$)? That is, is this the type of bound you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I think that is correct. And with other similar $R$'s, I think the trivial bound should be roughly that.

Comment: I think one of the points of the problem is how large or small should the entries of the multisets be. If they are too large close to $n$, then $a_2 + k + 1$ would exceed $n$ soon enough after a few additions (and you can't count these), similarly $a_1 - k$ decreases. There should be some kind of equilibrium eventually.

Comment: Thus I feel the maximum should correspond to the case when say $A_1$ has elements around $n/2$ and the other $A_i's$ are as close as possible to this.